# Razor MVC -How to creat an object from a form within view?

Tags: asp.net-core, object, model-view-controller, razor

I want to create a blog and add the entries to a list. So this is my object.

```
    namespace MyBlog.Models {
    public class Eintrag {
        public static List<Eintrag> Eintraege { get; set; } = new();
        public string BlogEintrag { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string BlogName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Untertitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}

This is the view

    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Eintrag verfassen";
}

<h1>Eintrag schreiben</h1>
<form action="/Home/Eintraege_anzeigen/" formmethod="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="BlogName">Blog</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="BlogName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title">Titel</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Untertitle">Untertitel</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Untertitle" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eintrag">Eintrag</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="BlogEintrag" id="eintrag"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Now i want to get the object to the list, either before or after it was submited.
How do i do that?
something like

```
Eintrag.Eintraege.Add(this);
<input type="submit" value="SEND">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`<form action="/Home/Eintraege_anzeigen/" formmethod="get">` into  `<form asp-action="Eintraege_anzeigen" method="post">`

In HomeController:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Eintraege_anzeigen(Eintrag Eintrag)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:

[image]

Have a look at [Overview of ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.